# The files with the extension bash and sh

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I made some researches about the files with `bash` and `sh` extensions. Most of the people and resources say that if a file has `bash` extension, then it contains `bash` scripts. Likewise, the file with `sh` extensions contains `sh` scripts.

However, I cannot find the differences between bash and sh scripting. There are some courses and articles which aim to teach the people to write scripts on shell, and all of them has the title `shell scripting`.

In this point, which one does shell scripting correspond to ?

Bash Scripting or Sh scripting.

What I try to understand is what is the difference between bash and sh scripting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

File names in POSIXland don't have "extensions".  A `.` in a filename is no different from any other character and has no specific meaning other than those that might be attributed to them by meatbags such as ourselves.

One could *hope* that any file with a name ending in `.bash` would be a script meant to be executed via the `bash` shell, but there is no guarantee of this.

Indeed, it's quite common to give *all* shell scripts a suffix of `.sh` no matter which interpreter is intended for their use, as the shebang line *should* properly specify which shell should be used to execute such a file.

`sh` and `bash` are two different, but related, shells; two amongst many others such as `ksh`, `csh`, `zsh`, `fish`, `ash`, `dash`, and yet more others.

Each shell has its own syntax, capabilities, mannerisms, and foibles; some shells are largely compatible with each other (generally any script written for `sh` can also be run in `bash` or many other shells), but some are not.

Comment: Isn't `sh` simply the machine's default shell (whether bash or ash or whatever)?  It's very likely to be a POSIX-compliant shell, and may use different settings when run as `sh`, but it's not necessarily a separate implementation or standard.

Answer (score 2):

The only significant issue I find day-to-day between `bash` and `sh` is the comparison operator.  In `bash` the double-equals operator `==` can be used for string comparison:

```
if [ "$var" == "foo" ]; then  # bash
```

But in `sh` this is a syntax error, as it expects single-equals.

```
if [ "$var" = "foo" ]; then   # sh
```

I am not saying this is the only difference, but this is a commonly found issue.

Comment: Search for `bashisms` to find out more differences.